# Java-Servlets: String null or "null"

Tags: string, servlets

[String says its not null but then later throw NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533662/testing-a-string-is-null)

I had this problem(see the link), where I was sure that a String is **null**, but in fact the String was **"null"**

jcasso told me:

> Since you get the string from a
>   servlet i can say that this is normal.
>
> Java converts a null string to a
>   "null" string on some conditions.

When this situations appear?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly when you use string concatenation or `String.valueOf()`:

```
String x = null;
String y = x + ""; // y = "null"
String z = String.valueOf(x); // z = "null"
```

(There are similar variants, such as using `StringBuilder.append((String) null)`.)